# Compartamos valores y misión de la comunidad con compañeros

Tags: discusión, anuncios

Muchas gracias a [@Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) por la traducción.

---

—¿Queremos ver más respuestas fascinantes?
—¡Sí!
—¿Queremos ver más preguntas interesantes?
—¡Definitivamente!

Entonces, ¿por qué no invitamos a compañeros y colegas que realizarán preguntas interesantes y compartirán nuevos enfoques para resolver problemas?

Me parece que uno de los mejores modos de involucrar a gente es compartir con ellos la misión y cultura de la comunidad, sus valores fundamentales. Explica *por qué* estamos cambiando el mundo a mejor y describe nuestro ambiente interno seguro.

Creo que sería genial tener banners que hablen sobre los [valores fundamentales](/help/key-values) y [misión](/help/manifesto) de la comunidad. Vamos a ponerlos tanto en Stack Overflow en inglés como en Stack Overflow en español.

> Por favor, comparte tus ideas con la comunidad:
>
> 1. ¿Cómo te gustaría que se viesen los banners que dirigirán a los usuarios al "[manifiesto](/help/manifesto)" y a los "[valores fundamentales](/help/key-values)"?
> 2. ¿Qué eslóganes e imágenes recomendarías para usar en esos banners?

Basados en vuestras notas y opiniones, crearemos los banners que serán vistos por millones de desarrolladores de habla hispana.

¡Por favor, compartid lo que pensáis de estos banners y de la idea en general! ¡Agradeceremos sus opiniones!

Answer (score 3):

Va, rompamos el hielo.

> 1. ¿Cómo te gustaría que se viesen los banners que dirigirán a los usuarios al "[manifiesto](/help/manifesto)" y a los "[valores fundamentales](/help/key-values)"?

Cuadrados, como los que suelen aparecer en la columna derecha.

> 2. ¿Qué eslóganes e imágenes recomendarías para usar en esos banners?

- ¿Dudas con Git? ¡Resuélvelas en Stack Overflow en español!
- "A mí también me gusta contribuir a que muchos programadores puedan resolver sus dudas en su idioma".

Answer (score 0):

A la pregunta 1.
Un marco destacado en la parte izquierda o derecha de la página estaría bien. Sin entorpecer el contenido importante.

A la pregunta 2.
- Creemos una comunidad tecnológica en español realmente gigante.
- Conocimiento en español accesible y de calidad.
- Contribuye y forma parte de una gran comunidad en tu idioma.

Cosas así...